# Converting query parameter to Set

Tags: spring-integration

I am having trouble converting a query parameter in CSV format to a `java.util.Set` in my Spring Integration inbound gateway.

My outbound gateway adds the parameter like `?ids=[ID_1, ID_2]`.

My inbound gateway is reading the whole parameter as a single element into a Set like `["ID_1, ID_2"]`.

I have created my own static helper method to convert the String to a Set but wonder if there is a way to do the conversion implicitly in Spring Integration?

Thanks for your help!

My code is below.

Outbound Gateway:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway 
url="MY_URL?ids={ids}&amp;foo={foo}"
request-channel="myChannel"
http-method="GET"
message-converters="myConverter"
header-mapper="myMapper"
expected-response-type="MyDto">
  <int-http:uri-variable name="ids" expression="payload"/>
  <int-http:uri-variable name="foo" expression="headers.foo"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Inbound Gateway:

```
<int:service-activator 
input-channel="myChannel"
expression="@'myService'.getStuff(payload.ids, headers.foo)"/>
```

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway 
id="myGateway"
request-channel="myChannel"
path="MY_URL"
message-converters="myConverter"
header-mapper="myMapper"
supported-methods="GET">
  <int-http:header name="foo" expression="#requestParams.foo"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

---

**EDIT**

This looks like it will solve my problem: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#payload-type-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use `org.springframework.util.StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet()`:

```
/**
 * Convert a comma delimited list (e.g., a row from a CSV file) into a set.
 * <p>Note that this will suppress duplicates, and as of 4.2, the elements in
 * the returned set will preserve the original order in a {@link LinkedHashSet}.
 * @param str the input {@code String}
 * @return a set of {@code String} entries in the list
 * @see #removeDuplicateStrings(String[])
 */
public static Set<String> commaDelimitedListToSet(@Nullable String str) {
```

Comment: Thank you. That is certainly nicer than my custom static method. I still feel like there must be a way to do it automatically in Spring Integration though.

Comment: No, that's not Spring Integration responsibility. Right, there is a `Converter` abstraction and we definitely may develop some `StringToSetConverter`, but that might be dangerous in other places. Anyway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#payload-type-conversion